# Detect digits rectangle then crop using ImageMagick or CoreImage in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm developing an OCR app that reads the digits and copy them to clipboard automatically instead of manually typing...
I'm using (**TesseractOCR**) ... But before recognizing and in the image manipulating I'm improving the image for better recognition.

I used ImageMagick library and the filtered image looks like this :

[image]

But the Output of recognition is :

```
446929231986789 //The first and last numbers (4 & 9) were added
```

So I Want to detect only the white box to crop ...

I know that **OpenCV** do the trick but unfortunately it's **C++** library and I don't speak that language :(

And I knew that iOS8 has a new **CIDetector** of type **Rectangles** but I don't want to neglect the previous versions of iOS

### MY IMAGEMAGICK Filter CODE :

```
//Starting
MagickWandGenesis();
magick_wand = NewMagickWand();

//Reading the image....
NSString *tempFilePath = //Path of image

// Monochrome image 
MagickQuantizeImage(magick_wand,2,GRAYColorspace,1,MagickFalse,MagickFalse);    

// Write to temporary file
MagickWriteImage(magick_wand,
                 [tempFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                 );

DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);//Free up memory

// Load UIImage from temporary file
UIImage *imgObj = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];

// Display on device
```

Many thanks ..

Comment: It's not an OCV question! Why you tag your question with it?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with simple pixel search. Since you want to crop the white area with digits all you need to do is to find left, right, top and bottom borders of the rectangle. Provided that rectangle is axis aligned and has enough white space around digits you should find first row or column that has continuous number of white pixels. For example to find left border (which I guess would be around 78th column) start searching from column 0 and go right. For each column count continuous white pixels (single for-loop from top to bottom). By continuous I mean series that is not interrupted by black one. If count will reach, say, 80% of height you have your left border. Do the rest accordingly starting from right side, top or bottom and move in the opposite direction. I guess there are some fancy procedures to detect the rectangle but your input has quite distinguishable characteristics. So instead of linking to some lib I suggest DIY. To speed things up you could increase your row by 2 or more. Or you could scale your image down, treshold it do 2 colors.

There is also one more way to do this. Flood-fill with white starting from one of the corners.